# Who has final authority over Air Force One?

Tags: usa, faa, us-air-force, pilot-authority, air-force-one

U.S. FAA FAR 91.3 ("Responsibility and authority of the pilot in command") says that:

> The pilot in command of an aircraft is directly responsible for, and
>   is the final authority as to, the operation of that aircraft.

When an aircraft is operating as Air Force One, it would normally be flown by the designated high ranking USAF Officer, as a military flight.

Is the President, as Commander in Chief of the armed forces, able to over-ride the authority of the pilot?

For example, if one of the current Boeing VC-25's engines flames out and the captain announces that he has made the decision to take an option/ turn back - can the President override this decision and force him/her to continue the flight?

Comment: Military pilots are not subject to FARs.

Comment: Last time [a president pressed a pilot to do what he thought was a bad idea](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/apr/07/pilots-plane-crash-smolensk-polish-president-pressured-land-thick-fog) was also the last time he was able to misuse his immense power.

Comment: I suppose in theory the president could fly his own plane. I never heard of a president doing so, but I have heard of two kings doing so.

Comment: @Joshua [George W. Bush did it during a carrier landing on the USS Abraham Lincoln on May 2, 2003](http://www.cnn.com/2003/ALLPOLITICS/05/01/bush.carrier.landing/) while he was in office. He didn't land, but he did have the controls at some point in the flight.

Comment: @RonBeyer, operating the flight controls is not the same thing as being the pilot in command.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### The pilot in command has final authority over Air Force One

[Air Force Instruction 11-202, Volume 3](http://static.e-publishing.af.mil/production/1/af_a3/publication/afi11-202v3/afi11-202v3.pdf) says the following in Chapter 1, part 1.1.1 (as in, the *very first thing in the document*):

> 1.1.1. Pilot  in  Command  Authority. The Pilot in Command (PIC), regardless  of rank, is responsible for, and is the final authority for the operation of the aircraft.

Just for fun, let's compare it to the civilian version that you referenced, [14 CFR 91.3](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/E63BBEDC3044A110852566CF00612076?OpenDocument):

> The pilot in command of an aircraft is directly responsible for, and is the final authority as to, the operation of that aircraft.

Wow! Basically identical **except that the military version goes out of its way to mention that rank is irrelevant**.

Comment: And if the POTUS is with any military personnel, there is granted to be someone on board that outranks the pilot.

Comment: And whose authority is sufficient to make an active pilot in command a pilot out of command?

Comment: Rank is not absolute, the military has a concept of a situational or occupational rank. For example, guards have full authority to stop higher-ranked personnel, and turn them away if they do not show the necessary credentials to enter.

Comment: @rackandboneman - Your comment made me wonder enough that I made it [a question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38255/167)

Comment: For comparison, is this still true for other US military aircraft?

Comment: @E.P. -- my understanding is *yes* -- the 11-202 is true for *all* USAF aircraft.  See [here](http://code7700.com/1982_fuel_leak.htm) for an example of that instruction in action.